# Is there a way to disable the volume buttons on an iPhone, using code from an app?

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

Basically, I want to make a FPS game, but use the Volume+ button to shoot, and the Volume- button to switch weapons, instead of having a UI on the screen.

Is there a way to disable the default functions of the volume buttons, and instead reroute it to my desired output?

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but I highly doubt it.  Most users wouldn't want apps to be able to hijack their volume controls and would expect them to work as usual across all programs, so I can't imagine the OS makers would offer that feature.

Comment: Hm I did this quite some time (years) ago in Android.. already then you had to root your device in order to allow that .. in the meantime it is for sure even more restricted... iOS no clue tbh

Comment: This is 12 years old ^^ https://answers.unity.com/questions/40216/accessing-the-physical-volume-buttons-on-iphone-or.html but I doubt it went more liberal from there ;)